# How to remove inactive block device from the /dev?

Tags: linux, block-device

I know, that the `/dev/sde` block device doesn't exist anymore (cause I've stopped a piece of software, which simulated it), but I still see it in the `lsblk` output and in the `/dev` directory.

When I try the `fdisk -l /dev/sde` command I see a lot of errors in the `syslog` (below):

```
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.631827] sd 49:0:0:1: [sde] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.631835] sd 49:0:0:1: [sde] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.631838] sd 49:0:0:1: [sde] Add. Sense: Logical unit not supported
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.631839] sd 49:0:0:1: [sde] CDB: 
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.631840] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 00
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.631845] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sde, sector 0
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.638989] sd 49:0:0:1: [sde] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.639024] sd 49:0:0:1: [sde] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.639026] sd 49:0:0:1: [sde] Add. Sense: Logical unit not supported
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.639027] sd 49:0:0:1: [sde] CDB: 
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.639029] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.639034] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sde, sector 0
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.639039] Buffer I/O error on dev sde, logical block 0, async page read
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.639857] sd 49:0:0:1: [sde] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.639859] sd 49:0:0:1: [sde] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.639861] sd 49:0:0:1: [sde] Add. Sense: Logical unit not supported
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.639862] sd 49:0:0:1: [sde] CDB: 
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.639862] Read(10): 28 00 00 01 86 98 00 00 08 00
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.639866] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sde, sector 99992
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.639884] sd 49:0:0:1: [sde] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.639886] sd 49:0:0:1: [sde] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.639887] sd 49:0:0:1: [sde] Add. Sense: Logical unit not supported
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.639887] sd 49:0:0:1: [sde] CDB: 
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.639888] Read(10): 28 00 00 01 86 98 00 00 08 00
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.639891] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sde, sector 99992
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.639892] Buffer I/O error on dev sde, logical block 12499, async page read
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.640065] sd 49:0:0:1: [sde] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.640068] sd 49:0:0:1: [sde] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.640069] sd 49:0:0:1: [sde] Add. Sense: Logical unit not supported
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.640070] sd 49:0:0:1: [sde] CDB: 
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.640071] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 00
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.640075] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sde, sector 0
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.640089] sd 49:0:0:1: [sde] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.640090] sd 49:0:0:1: [sde] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.640091] sd 49:0:0:1: [sde] Add. Sense: Logical unit not supported
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.640092] sd 49:0:0:1: [sde] CDB: 
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.640092] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.640095] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sde, sector 0
Sep 26 16:25:41 ubuntu3 kernel: [29651.640096] Buffer I/O error on dev sde, logical block 0, async page read
```

How should I tell Linux to remove the `/dev/sde` from its list of active block devices?

OS: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS with kernel 3.19.0-78-generic

(working as virtual machine under VMware Fusion 8.5.8 on MacBook)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove each path to the device from the SCSI subsystem

```
echo 1 > /sys/block/sde/device/delete
```

Note that the *entire command* needs to be executed as root - not just the part command before the output redirection. So if using `sudo`, do

```
sudo bash -c 'echo 1 > /sys/block/sde/device/delete'
```

Comment: Sometimes I don't know if it's `sde` or not... What's the most reliable way to make sure it's inactive? All the tools like `fdisk`, `blkid` and `lsblk` don't return errors on inactive devices, only the `cfdisk` shows `FATAL ERROR`

Comment: This throws a Permission Denied error on Ubuntu 20.04, even if running this as root.

Comment: Martin: if you used sudo, try sudo bash -c 'echo 1 > /sys/block/sdX/device/delete'.